# CodeIgniter 4 - Improved Auto Routing not working with AJAX request

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just started a new project with CodeIgniter and after installation with composer I noticed the following warning in `Routes.php`:

> // The Auto Routing (Legacy) is very dangerous. It is easy to create vulnerable apps...

So following the suggestion I set:

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

and in `Feature.php`:

```
public bool $autoRoutesImproved = true;
```

My default route in `Routes.php` at the moment:

```
$routes->get('/', 'Authentication::index');
```

This is the `Authentication` controller

```
class Authentication extends BaseController {

    public function index(): ResponseInterface {
        ...

        return $this->response
            ->setBody($this->twig->render('login/view.twig'))
            ->setStatusCode(302);
    }

    public function postLogin(): ResponseInterface {
        $authModel = new AuthenticationModel();

        $response = $authModel->verifyLogin($_POST['loginUsername'], $_POST['loginPassword']);

        return $this->response
            ->setBody($response)
            ->setStatusCode(200);
    }
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080` the login page loads as it should.

I perform an AJAX request on the login page to verify the user credentials so that the latter can log in; but I am getting 404 on the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/authentication/login`

This is the AJAX request:

```
pageLoginForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    let isValid = pageLoginForm.valid();
    if (isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: _baseUrl + 'authentication/login',
            data: pageLoginForm.serializeArray(),
            success: function (response) {
                response === 'login' ? window.location.reload() : $('#errorMsg').text(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#errorMsg').text('An error occurred!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I added the prefix "post" to my controller method as instructed by the [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/changelogs/v4.2.0.html#new-improved-auto-routing) but it's not working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Which line sets _baseUrl for your AJAX call?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find anything regarding capitalisation of controller methodnames during AJAX requests, but just to be sure, could you check whether you might need to route towards Login instead of login?

Comment: @KayAngevare `let _baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';`
I have tried `Login` as you suggested, still doesn't works :/
I tried `url: _baseUrl + 'login',` in my ajax request and in Routes.php: `$routes->post('/login', 'Authentication::login');` and it worked! I never had to define AJAX routes in `Routes.php` before but I guess it is the only I can make it work now :|

Comment: ```Important

For security reasons, if a controller is used in the defined routes, Auto Routing (Improved) does not route to the controller.```

Read more https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#auto-routing-improved

You using that controller once in Routes.php `$routes->get('/', 'Authentication::index');`

Answer (score 0):

It's a really frustrating issue with the pre-flight. Ajax made an options request to know if post is enebled. To solve this, make a controller to handle options requests whith:

```
php spark make:controller options
```

So modify controller in this way:

```
public function index()
{
    return $this->optionsHandler();
}

public function optionsHandler(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    return die();
}
```

Then inside Config/Routes.php Add:

```
$routes->options('(:any)', 'Options::optionsHandler');
```

Take a look how I've implemented this in my project:

https://github.com/Akir4d/AOP

I hope this helps!